# Perl post to php

Tags: php, json, linux, perl

Im am new to Perl, I have a script that gets all the data in my linux server, process the data and form it into json string.

The question is:
How can I get those data in my php code in another domain. I have no idea in this approach, my mentor said to post data from perl to php in which I don't know how.

Please Advise. :D

Comment: This is covered in many parts of Perl: http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm

Comment: can you give an overview on how it works ? just answer it below so that i can upvote anytime. thanks

Comment: I don't know the concept of this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send data to a server, you can use [`libwww`](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl), a library of modules for communicating across the web. The best place to start is probably the [LWP Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/libwww-perl/lwpcook.pod), which has some commonly-used recipes in it. Your scenario, posting json data to a php script, could be dealt with by creating a request using [`HTTP::Request`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request) and sending it using [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.10';
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON;

# gather your data
my $data = prepare_data();

# Create a POST request with the URL you want your data going to
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => "http://api.example.com/");
# set the content type as JSON
$req->content_type('application/json');
# encode the json, add it to the request
$req->content( encode_json $data );

# print out the request object as text
say $req->as_string;

# Create a user agent object
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
# send the request using LWP::UserAgent's request method
my $response = $ua->request($req);
# see what the response was
# LWP::UA has a handy is_success method for checking this
if (! $response->is_success) {
    die "LWP request failed! " . $response->status_line;
}

# print the whole response
say $response->as_string;

# get the contents of the response
my $content = $response->decoded_content;
```

That should give you a start, and the docs for the modules I've mentioned have more details.

Comment: by the way, the result of this is coming from the php ? 
with the design and others?

Comment: You'll need to set up your PHP script to deal with the request sent by the perl script. The server will deal with some requests (e.g. if you put the wrong URL in your request, the server will send back a 404 "not found" response), but you can set up your PHP script to send back an appropriate response to the data in your request.

Comment: As what I understand, the user use the url of my perl script. Then the script request to the php using post method that returns view to the user, am i correct ?

Comment: Are you going to be writing the PHP script too? The perl script should return some kind of result to the user -- it depends what you're using the script for. If it's run from the command line, you might just want to tell the user whether it was successful or not. If it's a web interface, you might want to show the user different pages depending on whether the script did its job or not.

Comment: Hi there, if the server to which I am sending data requires authentication/authorization, then how to modify this code? I am posting content to a server using its API key (in rest format). I have a key which is used as username while password field is left blank. kindly provide input. Thanks

Comment: It depends on what the server API is. Is there an auth endpoint that you need to login in to first? Sometimes you do an initial auth request and the server sends back a token that you would then add to all subsequent queries. Sometimes you have a pre-generated token that you add to the request headers.